# CMake QT_LIBRARIES binary equivilent

Tags: qt, qt4, cmake

I want to copy the required binary files in my post-build step. Is there a version of this variable listing the binary files associated with the libraries? Something like `${QT_BINARIES}` which would list the files specifically for the modules included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a $(QT_LIBRARIES), which will contain those Qt-dlls you requested (and their dependencies).

In combination with the variable $(QT_BINARY_DIR) you could reconstruct a list of the binaries. E.g. something like the following (stripped from my own post-build cmakefile) on Windows.

```
foreach( Qt_library ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
    get_filename_component( Qt_library_name ${Qt_library} NAME_WE )
    # Note: the following Regex works for me on windows, I am not sure if it 
    # fully portable.
    string( REGEX REPLACE "^lib(.*)" "\\1" Qt_library_name ${Qt_library_name} )

    set( Qt_shared_library ${QT_BINARY_DIR}/${Qt_library_name}.dll )
    if( EXISTS ${Qt_shared_library} )
        # Add it to the list of 'desired' qt-libraries for later installation
        list( APPEND Qt_Install_Libraries ${Qt_shared_library} )
    endif( EXISTS ${Qt_shared_library} )
endforeach( Qt_library ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
list( REMOVE_DUPLICATES Qt_Install_Libraries )
install( FILES ${Qt_Install_Libraries} DESTINATION bin COMPONENT ThirdParty )
```

In this case I used an install-command on the last line, but certainly you could replace it with a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider reviewing CMake's BundleUtilities capability, which analyzes shared library prerequisites, copies in necessary "non-system" libraries (and even fixes them up to use @executable_path references on the Mac), and leaves your executable ready to roll with its own private copies of the necessary libraries.

See the example here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/BundleUtilitiesExample

It's especially useful for pulling in only those Qt libraries actually referenced by your executable...

After this operation, you're left with a "stand-alone" copy of your bundle app (or executable with shared libraries in the same directory) that can be safely copied to another machine.